# How to remove the thin line on the edge of LibreOffice GUI menu bar?

Tags: kde, libreoffice, kde-neon

How do I get rid of this thin line in the menu bar of LibreOffice and other applications? Previously I used [Elementary OS](https://elementary.io/) which did not show that thin line didn't exist. After changing to [KDE Neon](https://neon.kde.org/), that thin line appears.

[image: Thin Line]

Comment: Could you please provide more details, such as your distribution, its version, etc.? Same goes for LibreOffice.

Comment: I use distribution KDE Neon 5.15 User Edition. And for LibreOffice, i use LibreOffice 6.2 with user interface "Tabbed".

Comment: Could you add these details in your question, please? Also, could you add the output of `uname -a` and `libreoffice --help` typed inside a terminal?

Comment: _Tea Party_, please click [edit] to enhance or amend your question with newly requested information. It's far better to do that vs adding another Comment, as when Comments pile up, they roll off the screen.